# Preventing apps to access info from wifi device?

Tags: wireless-networking, browser, privacy, geolocation, privacy-protection

Browsers like Chrome and Firefox can use my wifi device to get information about the surrounded APs and pin point my physical location using Google Location Services, I know these browser always ask for permissions to do this, and that these features can also be "turned off". But I was wondering if there's a better way to prevent ANY application to access this information from my wifi device. I don't like anyone on the internet knowing where I live, and I am worried some software could do the same as these browsers but without asking for permissions.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0):

"Turning them off" is the best way...

In Firefox: Navigate to about:config and change "geo.enabled" to off.

In Chrome: Click Wrench menu , click Options and click Under the Hood Tab and in Privacy click Content Settings and click Location under Location Settings select Do not allow any site to track my physical location and Close.

You could also utilize a proxy or use VPN to connect to another computer and browse through that connection.